# no such file or directory: /Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh, home-directory, username

I am using macOS+iTerm+ZSH. I changed my home directory name and name and now I am getting an error looks like down below:

```
/Users/new_username/.zshrc:source:75: no such file or directory: /Users/old_username/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

How can I solve this,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was a quicky one, sorry it is 3am in here and I am little unconscious.

So I figured I can still use terminal and there was a file like /Users/new_username/.zshrc and the 4th line of this document was like `export ZSH="/Users/old_username/.oh-my-zsh"` and after I changed the path, boom, problem solved.

Hope it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so the question doesn't stay open.

Comment: Did it, I wasn't aware of this, sorry.